# How to fit text into shape made with shapebuilder and keep upright

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So I've figured out how to fit text into a shape by using envelope distortion, but when I do it, the text looks weird like in the picture below. How do I make the lowercase letters fill it in evenly and make it so the letters don't slant so much? Is it the font? Thanks!

[image].

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, nothing which "distorts" a text object is going to work for you.

The primary issue is that distortions see the *bounding box* of a text object as the "shape" to distort. They do *not* factor in upper/lowercase type. So the Envelope Distort doesn't know there are lower case, smaller, letters on the right side. It **only sees the rectangular bounding box** of the *entire type object*. You can try and alter the mesh created by the envelope to "lift" the right side middle a bit. This *might* distort those glyphs to a more readable state. In many instances that's more a lesson in frustration than anything else.

You can **try** outlining the type (`Type > Create Outlines`) and *then* applying an Envelope Distort via top object. This will allow the envelope to actually see the shapes of the type and apply that distortion to the top object. However, in many instances this will result in *far too much* overall distortion of the glyphs themselves and make readability a challenge in many instances.

Really, for the best possible outcome you need to *manually* edit each type glyph. That is - **create outlines then *manually* alter the glyphs** - change their size, alter curves, move anchors if necessary, etc.

The only way you will get any sort of viable output with this type of distortion, *without* manual manipulation, is by using all uppercase type which may or may not convey the message in the same manner camel case type would. For a script font, such as the one you are using, all uppercase type tends to look pretty bad.

Note that **Type on a Path may also be a viable option for you**. It is difficult to state definitively without testing the same font you are using (No clue that that may be). However, Type on a Path won't distort *anything* other than baseline and x/y of the glyphs. With some monitor size alterations you *might* find Type on a path yields more visually appealing results.

Answer (score 0):

An old case, popped up by the system.

You have already got the receipe of the perfect result: Modify and place the glyphs manually one by one. No problem as long as you have well trained editing hands and sharp eyes which see exactly beforehand what's needed.

I guess many of us want something easier. You can try this:

[image]

1. The starting point: A text and the problematic space
2. Draw an intermediate curve (=the halfway version). Theoretically blending would make it perfectly, but only if there's not too many nodes or at least the nodes are distributed equally in the upper and lower border curve. This is drawn with the pen. It's a little too long as we see later.
3. Outline a copy of your text. Drag it to the brushes collection and define it to be an art brush. Apply that brush to your curve

4 and 5. Edit the curve with the width tool and with the direct selection tool. This needed a couple of edits with both of them

Another "shortcut" is to use envelope distortion as you have already tried. You get an envelope which deforms the text at least to the right direction by applying Make with Warp > Flag:

[image]

Then edit the nodes and handles of the envelope with the Direct Selection Tool. Every node has 2...3 handles which also must be tweaked to get this:

[image]